# How to check if span has value even after the website refreshes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I would like to ask if it is possible to maintain the changes from a function after the whole website refreshes. So far I found a code for changing background color of a span who has a value. But then since it is onclick, the background color changes back to original as the page refreshes.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
   $('td span').each(function(index){
       if( $(this).text().length !== 0 ){
          $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
       }
   });       
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/7kpr6vun/22/)**

Is there a way to maintain the changes even after the page refreshes or is there another way to do it? A listener maybe or a checker in which the site will be checked first whether the span has value or not. Also instead of making the parent's background color change I want the column on the opposite to change. The one without a value. Will it be possible? Javascript or Jquery is okay.

**EDIT**

Uhmm I guess my question was a bit unclear. Well I edited my code above. You can see there the table in which there are 2 columns. I want it to retain that way after the page refreshes. But so far I get stuck with modifying the code.. and it doesn't save the color anymore. I think that I made a mistake along the way but I cannot figure it out.. :(

**[JSFIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/7kpr6vun/28/)**

**UPDATE**

Okay another try at @trincot's answer, I kinda found what I was looking for but not quite. Its a bit long and its unnecessary to highlight the text and for inputting text. The whole box should be painted not highlighted. Please refer to this **[JSFIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/7kpr6vun/22/)**. Below is the one I modified.

**[JSFIDDLE 3](https://jsfiddle.net/1jt52z2x/)**

Comment: check out using LocalStorage!

Comment: @SatejS I have checked out the local storage but it seems in order to save the value to local storage you have to input values first. What I have is like a validation error. The error only shows up after it has been verified that the input is wrong and that the css will also changed.

Comment: I tried something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7kpr6vun/7/)

Comment: @SatejS I see but everything gets painted yellow. x.x I only wanted to paint the td with values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As PartyPete25 suggested, We can make use of HTML5 localstorage.

Here's working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrajesh/kyh7ns7w/4/)

So here is the code for you,

```
    <table border="1px" width="50%">
  <tr>
    <td><span class="bgValue"></span></td>
    <td><span class="bgColor">1</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="bgValue"></span></td>
    <td><span class="bgColor">5</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="bgValue"></span></td>
    <td><span class="bgColor">8</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Try it" />
```

JS

```
var tdValue = $('.bgValue');

 var storedBgColor = localStorage.getItem('.bgColor');

 if (storedBgColor) {
   tdValue.parent().css('background-color', storedBgColor);
 } else {
   // set default color
   alert('no color set');

 }


 $('input').click(function() {

   $('td span').each(function(index) {

     if ($(this).text().length !== 0) {
       $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
       var bgColor = $('.bgColor');

       localStorage.setItem('.bgColor', 'yellow');


       // When a span with some value is found, alert the index of the row
       alert($(this).closest('tr')[0].rowIndex);

     }

   });
 });
```

Comment: Oh cool! but if I want to color the opposite of the span with text?

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! I have a bit same of a code but I lost half way. xD

Comment: I dunno why but it isn't working when I put it in my website.. :(

Comment: Have you added JQuery in your script... What's the 'console error'?

Comment: Yes I did. It was working before but it wasn't right. I guess I have done something wrong. I'm trying to find out. x.x

Comment: Did you find any 'Console Error'

Comment: Ah yes, I was modifying it because when I click the  button everything is painted yellow but only one span have a value. :(

Comment: Is it like everything in the left paints yellow?

Comment: Yes everything in the left gets painted in yellow even if the right side has no value. It should only be painted yellow if the rightside has value. Please check my question again for I have updated it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either;

a) HTML5 Local Storage - http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp or,

b) JavaScript cookies - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

HTML Storage example:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   // update on click
   $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');

  // set local stoarge to true so that it'll work after a refresh
  if (!localStorage.clicked) {
    localStorage.clicked = true;
  }

});

// check on document ready
$(function(){
if (localStorage.clicked) {
  $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I will try to use it in accordance to my website. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some suggested code:

```
function highlightTexts() {
   var texts = [];
   $('td span').each(function(index){
       texts.push($(this).text());
       if( $(this).text().length !== 0 ){
          $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'yellow');
       }
   });
   var json = JSON.stringify(texts);
   sessionStorage.setItem('span-texts', json);
   // Cancel the form submission. Maybe you don't need this
   return false; 
}

$('#submit').click(highlightTexts);

$(function() {
   var json = sessionStorage.getItem('span-texts');
   if (json) {
       var texts = JSON.parse(json);
       $('td span').each(function(index){
           $(this).text(texts[index]);
       });
       highlightTexts();
   }
});
```

Here is a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1y5y8pth/1/) which demonstrates you can save texts which are loaded again when refreshing or revisiting the same page again. The texts are then highlighted again using the same algorithm as used at submission.

Comment: Thank You for your answer but it wasn't what I was looking for. :D

Comment: Would you care to explain what you are missing in this answer? Did I misunderstand your question? This code successfully checks if span has value when page refreshes, like I thought you asked.

Comment: Hi~ I updated my question please kindly check it. Thank you very much! Your code has been helpful.

Comment: How is the text in the spans changed? By the user? If it is static, then why would you need to save the highlights? If it is generated, why don't you apply the highlighting at that time?

Comment: It is static but once the button was clicked and the span shows up the left column should be painted. I needed it to be saved because when the button is clicked the whole page refreshes and the paint that I have painted gets reset.

Comment: But then you better look into why the page refreshes, and circumvent that, no?

Comment: Ah yes I finally get the code working right. Thank you very much! :D It turns out that I just needed a simple code. xD

Comment: I believe `return false` is the key in avoiding the refresh, which is why I put the code comment *"Cancel the form submission."*.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much~ :D